# Show bootstrap popover after submitting form that is in modal

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, submit, show, popover

I have a form, that is in remote modal window. Here is the modal in index.html:

```
<a data-toggle="modal"  href="contact.html" data-target="#myModal">Contact Me</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Than here is acctual form in contact.html:

```
<script>
    $('#pop').popover({content: 'Message send.'},'click');    
</script>

<form id="contactform" method="post" action="data/send_mail.php">
    <!--
    here is whole form content
    -->
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-custom" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" id="pop">Send</button>
</form>
```

Now my **problem is:** I need to show bootstrap popover after not clicking on the submit button but when the form is really send. I do the validation in browser(no php regular expressions or jQuery validate, simply in browser).
My approach was following (after gathering the data from from and creating message in send_mail.php):

```
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    /* Here should be something that will make my popover show, like: echo ('$('#pop').popover('show')');*/
sleep(2);
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content=\"0; url=../index.html\">";
```

But this second command (in comment does not work). I am total newbie in php, so I try to make my solutions as simple as possible. I hope that I have explained my problem properly.
Thx...

Comment: it would be convenient to use ajax to send the message and get the success response after sending or an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting an `action` to the form you can just leave it blank and do the submit call using jquery.

**SCRIPT**

This script will be able communicate with your `data/send_mail.php` and by getting the value from the `html input` which has an `id of name` we can pas that as a parameter to the `send_mail.php`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myButton').on('submit', function(){
            var data_value = $('#name').val();
            var data_value2 = $('#name2').val();
            var data_value3 = $('#name3').val();
            var url = 'data/send_mail.php';
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data:{'data_to_pass':data_value,
                           'second_data': data_value2,
                            'third_data': data_value3},
            success:function(){   
                $('#pop').popover('show'); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

the complete URL will be `data/send_mail.php?data_to_pass=data_value`

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="input something here" required />
    <button id="button" type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-custom" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" id="pop">Send</button>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I wrote, I am new to all of this. So I am lost. Could you maybe also explain the code a little bit, so I will also learn something instead of copying? And is this based on my code from above? Why is there process_date_to.php and 'date_from':dateFrom ?

Comment: oops, that url is a typo, ok lemme edit it with some explaination, and based it on ur code

Comment: now check it and tell me if you understand and also the `<form></form>` tag is not much needed there, so u can either get rid of it or just make it stay as it is.

Comment: Thx a lot. I am beginning to understand :D And how can I send more data than just one input? My form contains: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Full name">`, `<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required="required" placeholder="you@example.com">`, `<textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" required="required" rows=8 placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>`

Comment: sorry couldn't read your code like that bro, i edited it for more than one data, and if its the right answer you can mark as correct and vote it also :)

Comment: And I also guess that in the second line of your code - $('#myButton') you are referencing to that submit button, just to make things clear, which in my case has the id='pop'. So it should be $('#pop'), that you use when you are calling popover. Am I right?

Comment: yup, in your case it should be `#pop` and not `#button`, and either way, the `popover` will be called if the ajax is successful, and you can also make a return string like `success` or `error` and passing that as a parameter in the `success function` so you can customized the popover a little.